# How can I add attributes to an img tag to use in an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code I have. This can not be changed, I have to work with the structure as is.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="contain_box">
    <a href="something">
       <img class="my_img" src="some_image">
    </a>
    <div class="variants">
       <div class="var" rel="123" data="321"></div>
       <div class="var" rel="1234" data="4321"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contain_box">
    <a href="something">
       <img class="my_img" src="some_image">
    </a>
    <div class="variants">
       <div class="var" rel="456" data="654"></div>
       <div class="var" rel="4567" data="7654"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contain_box">
    <a href="something">
       <img class="my_img" src="some_image">
    </a>
    <div class="variants">
       <div class="var" rel="789" data="987"></div>
       <div class="var" rel="7890" data="0987"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I need is when I click on one of the images it will pull the rel and the data from its first variant, add those attributes to the image tag. Right now I am trying this and I only get the undefined. I am using the undefined to clear out those variables from the current values.

```
$(document).on("click", '.my_img', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    data = undefined;
    rel = undefined;

    var new_rel = $('.var').attr('rel');
    var new_data = $('.var').attr('data');

    $('.my_img').attr('rel', new_rel);
    $('.my_img').attr('data', new_data);

    data = $(this).attr('variant');
    rel = $(this).attr('rel');
}
```

Any insights or help would be awesome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: rel attribute is not in image its in div

Comment: where is the ajax you mentioned?

Comment: you could set the 'alt' attribute of the img tag to the value you need.

Comment: I have the ajax section working. I could have been more clear, I need those two values to run it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the parent container (`.contain_box`) relative to the clicked image, then the first variant from there:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K2btj/)**

```
$(document).on("click", '.my_img', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var firstVariant = $(this).closest('.contain_box').find('.var').first();
    data = firstVariant.attr('rel');
    rel = firstVariant.attr('data');

    $(this).attr({
        data : data,
        rel : rel
    });

    console.log(data);
    console.log(rel);
});
```

Comment: You rock MrCode thank you much this solved my issue!